# Symfony2 multiple select tags from one entity

Tags: php, symfony

Soo, the problem would be following:

I have entity `Group` in relation with entity `Student` (OneToMany).

```
Group1 has Student1 and Student2
Group2 has Student3 and Student4
```

Also I have entity `Class` which is the main one for form to render. Form should be parsed something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="class[name]"> <-- this one easy
```

Problem begins here: (I need to render dynamically so many `select` tags how many there is records in `Group` entity with `Student` entity records (related) in options)

```
<label>Group1</label>
<select name="class[group][0]"> <-- don't not exactly about `name` attr
    <option value="1">Student 1</option>
    <option value="2">Student 2</option>
</select>

<label>Group2</label>
<select name="class[group][student]"> <-- or something
    <option value="3">Student 3</option>
    <option value="4">Student 4</option>
</select>
```

And so on..

I've read about custom field types, but could find example how to do it.
And have no idea where to begin searching.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATED**

```
class ClassType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Class'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'class';
    }
}
```

GroupType

```
class GroupType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Group'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'b';
    }
}
```

StundentType

```
class StudentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('group')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Student'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'student';
    }
}
```

Class entity

```
class Class
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return A
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Group entity

```
class Group
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Student", mappedBy="group")
     */
    private $students;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return B
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->students = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add students
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\C $students
     * @return B
     */
    public function addStudent(\AppBundle\Entity\C $students)
    {
        $this->students[] = $students;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove students
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\C $students
     */
    public function removeStudent(\AppBundle\Entity\C $students)
    {
        $this->students->removeElement($students);
    }

    /**
     * Get students
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getStudents()
    {
        return $this->students;
    }
}
```

Student entity

```
class Student
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="students")
     */
    private $group;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return C
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set group
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\B $group
     * @return C
     */
    public function setGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\B $group = null)
    {
        $this->group = $group;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get group
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\B 
     */
    public function getGroup()
    {
        return $this->group;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use formType based on your entities

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html

Choice field for this purpose :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

In the Symfony console you can generate the formType with doctrine command :

```
generate
 generate:bundle                          Generates a bundle
 generate:controller                      Generates a controller
 --> generate:doctrine:crud               Generates a CRUD based on a Doctrine entity
 generate:doctrine:entities               Generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information
 generate:doctrine:entity                 Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle
 --> generate:doctrine:form               Generates a form type class based on a Doctrine entity
```

Generate a formType with **generate:doctrine:form** and un CRUD controller with **generate:doctrine:crud** it's help you to see how to use formType :)

EDIT :
lead to do the form :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-user-data
Using this example as base

Comment: But wouldn't it allow to select only groups, not group students?

Comment: Can you post your entities ?  
If I'm right you have a student key in your group entity, when you create a form, you use an entity, if you use the first group, you have the students for the first group.  
Perhaps you relation is not the better for your problem.  
Can you say the purpose of you form ?

Comment: Thanks, and what is the goal of your form ?  
You do you need select of students ?

Comment: I need render so many selects as there are groups and with students in option. See HTML example. And I need it to save in DB like Class has group with student.

| class_id | group_id | student_id | or smthg like that

Comment: This is the part I don't understand, you need to save a class with related group and student ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106447/discussion-between-darjus-ilcevic-and-nicolas).